# Firebase message, Android app in background not intercept push notification after click on message

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I use firebase messaging to send push notification. I have a small problem with my android app. In the iOS version, I can easily pass parameters after clicking on a notification when the app is in background.

In Android version I can intercept messages when the app is in the foreground, but not when the app is in the background (I use library com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.4):

my AndroidManifest.xml

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        >

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="OPEN_NOTIFY" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
....
<service
        android:name=".MyFirebaseMessagingService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

My notification payload:

```
notification:{
 title: "mytitle",
 text: "MYTEXT",
 "data":{
   "type" : "message",
   "id_message" : res
  },
  "click_action" : "OPEN_NOTIFY"
},to: token
```

When I click on the notification, it should open the MainActivity and I would like to have the id_message

my MyFirebaseMessagingService.java

```
 @Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage){

    //never enters if the app is in background

    if(remoteMessage.getNotification() != null){
       //I READ NOTIFY WHEN APP IS IN FOREGROUND
    }
}
```

I try to get parameters directly from the Inten, but this solution doesn't work

my MainActivity.java:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   ....
   if (getIntent().getExtras() != null) {
        for (String key : getIntent().getExtras().keySet()) {
            Object value = getIntent().getExtras().get(key);
            Log.d(TAG, "Key: " + key + " Value: " + value);
        }
    }
   ....
}
```

I can't intercept my notify:

output:

```
Key: google.sent_time Value: 1540026384768
Key: google.ttl Value: 2419200
Key: from Value: 635549396240
Key: google.message_id Value: 0:1540026384773623%6b8fed3d6b8fed3d
Key: collapse_key Value: ....
```

Am I following the right path? Thank You

Answer (score 0):

According to [official Firebase docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive#handling_messages), you can't handle notification{} part of notification (you can only set icon of it in manifest), BUT here's solution: send necessary data via data{} part. You can now handle it with MyFirebaseService and show notification if you want and as you want: data will appear in `remoteMessage.toIntent().getExtras()`.
In your case, send notification like this:

```
// ignore notification {}
data {
    "type" : "message",
    "id_message" : res
}
to: key
```

(do not place data into notification block)
I can write working code of sending and receiving notification, if you want